# Filtering outliers

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a question. My data is:

```
A = {
   {0.2, 0.40146281474615786}, {0.4, 0.43729919084481816},
   {0.6, 0.4470564180162124}, {0.8, 0.45881616535324715},
   {1., 0.4509532203448973}, {1.2, 0.4391097035918376},
   {1.4, 0.41600679553303455}, {1.6, 0.38306857448556514},
   {1.8, 0.3481668688503314}, {2., 0.2983421436262226},
   {2.2, 0.2557346328339622}, {2.4, 0.19446641328439063},
   {2.6, 0.14847512562986234}, {2.8, 0.08189392350583746},
   {3., 0.036673209483593996}, {3.2, -0.028981094048737513},
   {3.4, -0.06978223958320823}, {3.6, -0.12871746387125604},
   {3.8, -0.16221027579956004}, {4., -0.20957028588350132},
   {4.2, -0.2337849790147304}, {4.4, -0.26602979956936895},
   {4.6, -0.2799754162807263}, {4.8, -0.29512485011473866},
   {5., -0.29875700778262654}, {5.2, -0.29648274317585716},
   {5.4, -0.2905938570245873}, {5.6, -0.27215908344120876},
   {5.8, -0.2582110339142754}, {6., 0},
   {6.2, -0.20619211967725673}, {6.4, -0.16447509412947287},
   {6.6, -0.14044940059583255}, {6.8, -0.09336450554215069},
   {7., -0.06762124606636702}, {7.2, -0.019816026463068407},
   {7.4, 0.005546793434134096}, {7.6, 0.049624552224691365},
   {7.8, 0.07278355054107674}, {8., 0.10928469927062807},
   {8.2, 0.1287900597985716}, {8.4, 0.15478801651540255},
   {8.6, 0.16961779074075561}, {8.8, 0.18333104078552429},
   {9., 0.1929042351357314}, {9.2, 0.193801357661145},
   {9.4, 0.19795654126155918}, {9.6, 0.18673927023817513},
   {9.8, 0.18568738827251755}, {10., 0.16415877017121053},
   {10.2, 0}, {10.4, 0.12925462418916733},
   {10.6, 0.11958450613260761}, {10.8, 0.08603023215218146},
   {11., 0.07335073027548773}, {11.2, 0.038885092730455095},
   {11.4, 0.02421425495580898}, {11.6, -0.00779885211923696},
   {11.8, -0.023407245963763756}, {12., -0.050035776716621225},
   {12.2, -0.06554512227613181}, {12.4, -0.0845492160732084},
   {12.6, -0.09898557992959466}, {12.8, -0.10899795412525494},
   {13., -0.12148955926133687}, {13.2, -0.12210197556583759},
   {13.4, -0.13191416471922315}, {13.6, -0.12366570374902539},
   {13.8, -0.13023232414283864}, {14., -0.11450499510526209},
   {14.2, -0.11745616038384582}, {14.4, -0.0962922781400379},
   {14.6, -0.09547728860382289}, {14.8, -0.07134021778949663},
   {15., -0.0668433407322323}, {15.2, -0.04234797914502431},
   {15.4, 0}, {15.6, -0.012135420008349348},
   {15.8, -0.0014822151818331835}, {16., 0.01661054922359618},
   {16.2, 0.029296140761400156}, {16.4, 0.04155634296128359},
   {16.6, 0.05533939194097194}, {16.8, 0.06089246099126517},
   {17., 0.07472833356451251}, {17.2, 0.0734440579587264},
   {17.4, 0.08625147994300575}, {17.6, 0.07871696040196116},
   {17.8, 0.08946123870264909}, {18., 0.07688082309933156},
   {18.2, 0.08466069430795062}, {18.4, 0.06869648269501011},
   {18.6, 0.072826674053179}, {18.8, 0.05539882677986384},
   {19., 0.05547983606927061}, {19.2, 0.038549368737800946},
   {19.4, 0.03451635961065957}, {19.6, 0.019874071482120136},
   {19.8, 0.012018184150081311}, {20., 0.0011018149980739707`}};
```

It is an set defining the funtion y = f(x).

How can I delete the outliers based on the condition: remove the points from the set A, where the derrivative of the function y has a big deviation.Therefore, plot the new function y = f(x) based on the filtered data.

Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the answer, it seems a bit different just because the data in this case lends itself to a nice analytic fit.

Answer (score 6):

In this case, instead of analysing derivatives, prediction intervals can be used to identify the outliers.

A nonlinear fit is made to the equation for a damped sinusoid.

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[A, {a Exp[-b t] Cos[c t + d]}, {a, b, c, d}, t];

{cl68, cl95, cl99} = Map[2 (CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], #] - 0.5) &, {1, 2, 3}];

{bands68[t_], bands95[t_], bands99[t_]} = Table[nlm["SinglePredictionBands",
    ConfidenceLevel -> cl], {cl, {cl68, cl95, cl99}}];

Show[ListPlot[A], Plot[{nlm[t], bands68[t], bands95[t], bands99[t]},
  {t, 0, 20}, Filling -> {2 -> {1}, 3 -> {2}, 4 -> {3}}], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {-0.5, 0.5}}, ImageSize -> 480, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

For example, selecting points deviating by more than half a standard deviation.

```
σ = 0.5; cl = 2 (CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], σ] - 0.5);

bands = nlm["SinglePredictionBands", ConfidenceLevel -> cl];

test[p_] := Module[{x, y, y0lo, y0hi},
  {x, y} = p;
  {y0lo, y0hi} = bands /. t -> x;
  y0lo < y <= y0hi]

result = test /@ A;

ok = Pick[A, result];
notok = Pick[A, Not /@ result];

Show[ListPlot[ok], ListPlot[notok,
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]